Interpretation of $P(x_i > y_j) = P(y_j > x_i)$
Let's consider a sample of $n$ observations $\{x_i\} = \{x_1, x_2, \ldots x_n\}$ from a population $X$ and a sample of $m$ observations $\{y_j\} = \{y_1, y_2, \ldots y_m\}$ from a population $Y$.
In the Wikipedia article about the Mann–Whitney $\displaystyle U$ test (also called Wilcoxon rank-sum test), we read that the alternative hypothesis of that test, is something like this:

The probability of an observation $x_i$ from population $X$ exceeding
an observation $y_j$ from population $Y$ is different (larger, or smaller)
than the probability of an observation $y_j$ from $Y$ exceeding an
observation $x_i$ from $X$, i.e.
$P(x_i > y_j) \neq P(y_j > x_i)$
(or $P(x_i > y_j) + 0.5 · P(x_i = y_j) \neq 0.5$)

I guess that the null hyptohesis is the opposite condition, i.e.:
$P(x_i > y_j) = P(y_j > x_i)$
(or $P(x_i > y_j) = \frac{1}{2}$)
I am trying to understand the meaning of those probabilities.
Does $P(x_i > y_j) = P(y_j > x_i)$ mean that the two populations/distributions $X$ and $Y$ are identical to each other? Or there could be other interpretations?

Simply knowing that those two probabilities are the same certainly doesn't tell you that the distributions are the same.  Say $X=0,1$ with equal probability and $Y=-1$ with probability $\frac 12$ and $Y=2,3$ each with probability $\frac 14$.

Thanks, even though I did not understand your example (Did you mean $X=(0,1)$ and $Y=(-1,2,3)$? i.e. $x_1=0$, $x_2=1$ and $y_1=-1$, $y_2=2$, and $y_3=3$?)

I am saying that $X$ takes either the value $0$ or the value $1$, with equal probability and that $Y$ takes any of the values $-1, 2, 3$ but not with equal probabilities ($\frac 12$ for $-1$ and $\frac 14$ for each of $2,3$).  Easy to see that the chance that $Y>X$ is $\frac 12$, as is the chance that $X>Y$, taking $X,Y$ to be independent, of course.

Ah ok, thanks :-)

However, in Karch (2021) (https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/2515245921999602), in Section "Multiple perspectives on the
Mann-Whitney test", he lists several "perspectives" of the Mann–Whitney  test, i.e. : (1) "Equality of distributions - Null hypothesis: Population distributions are equal in all aspects", (2) "_Equality of medians

Null hypothesis: Population medians are
equal_", and (3) "_Stochastic equality
Null hypothesis: $P(X>Y) = P(Y>X)$_".


Therefore, if the $P(X>Y) = P(Y>X)$ means a "stochastic equality", why does another "perspective" of that test is about "Equality of distributions"?

That's what "stochastic equality" means.  I mean, that's the definition.  See, e.g., this.

Thanks a lot :-) (however, I am not able to "see" why a  "stochastic equality" would be considered as a another perspective of the "Equality of distributions" according to the Karch (2021) paper....)

I have no idea what that author might have in mind, but the example I linked to should give you some perspective.  The notion arises whenever you have subjectively defined measurements for which the particular magnitude of an observation may be less important than relative measures (large v. small).

Just noticed that my link is authored by the same person you are quoting.

Thanks a lot :-) ...Yes, he is the same author of the post :-)

The natural use of this test is whether the two distributions are identical, but in fact its construction cannot distinguish between identical distributions and the more general $P(X_i > Y_j) = P(Y_j > X_i)$ (which is then only $\frac12$ if $P(X_i = Y_j)=0$)
